# Is there a complete list of all Shimano bicycle components?

Tags: shimano, parts

You can search for specific components on [si.shimano.com](https://si.shimano.com/en/) and [VeloBase](https://velobase.com/ViewBrand.aspx?BrandID=f9a4c79f-2ff6-4c5c-8b41-9f199d0d2106&From=T) has a huge database of Shimano components, but it's far from being complete. Is there a definitive list of all Shimano components ever released?

Comment: No.  Those two would have the bulk of items covered between them, with a lot of overlap.   Is there a question underneath your question?  ie, are you searching for something ?

Comment: The Wikipedia page for Shimano lists all the road and MTB groupsets that Shimano has made, with series numbers and years they were current

Comment: Shimano released quit a few components not associated with any groupset, some of them where really neat. The FC-R700 and the BL-R600 come to mind. I'm trying to expand my knowledge about those "hidden" components.

Answer (score 2):

Without being definitive (from 2004 to today), a good way I can think of is going to the [archive section](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/archive) of the Shimano technical documentation website. By opening the *specifications* documents, you have access to all the parts they released over a given year sorted by category of bikes (MTB, Road, etc) and then by family of components (Brake, Crankset, etc).

The non-series components will display *SHIMANO* in the *Series* row. For example, here is an excerpt from such documents:

[image]